# Dao design pattern for only data retrieval. Is it necessary?

Tags: java, mysql, design-patterns, dao

Is it recommended to use DAO design pattern for jdbc connection if you only want to read data and not to do all CRUD operations?

Comment: I believe for sake of beeing independet of implementation and future extensions that could bring CRUD, it would be beneficial to use it. You lose nothing, at least from my perspective.

Comment: I'm curious where you plan on putting your DB-specific logic. The main benefit of DAO is that you avoid mixing levels of abstraction. As long as you accomplish that, you are fine. But if you find yourself handling DB exception in business logic classes, you need a different solution.

Comment: Actually i want to read from a relational database (mysql), filter the data and then store it in MongoDb

Comment: In addition, it provides a convenient place to mock for testing purposes, as well as being consistent with other parts of your system, and most other systems for that matter. This makes it easier for a new developer to understand.